# input for a String variable is skipped when it is preceeded by an integer input

Tags: java, string, integer, java.util.scanner

i was practicing  scanner usage and syntax and below is the code i wrote, where I am trying to take 4 inputs from the user :

```
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int a = s.nextInt();// taking an integer as input, it works fine.
    String b = s.nextLine();//was supposed to take a string input, but not working
    String c=s.nextLine();//takes a string as input from user
    String d=s.nextLine();//takes another string as input from user

    System.out.println("integer entered: "+a);
    System.out.println("first string entered: "+b);
    System.out.println("second string entered: "+c);
    System.out.println("third string entered: "+d);
```

but the user is able to give only 3 inputs, the first integer and other two string inputs and by printing the values of these 4 variables, it is clear that input for first string `String b` is skipped.I then tried to rearrange the sequence in which the input was taken, i.e,

```
String b = s.nextLine();//takes a string input
int a = s.nextInt();// taking an integer as input
String c=s.nextLine();//was supposed to take a string as input from user
String d=s.nextLine();//takes another string as input from user
```

in this case, the input for the second string `String c`is skipped.
So, is it because of the integer input that skips the next string input?

Comment: You've read the integer of the first line with `Scanner.nextInt()`, but not the rest of the line it was on : `.nextInt()` doesn't consume the linefeed. Add an extra `.nextLine()` after the `.nextInt()` to consume and discard the (empty) rest of the first line.

Comment: Or ParseInt the nextLine()... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common question.

---

Fixed code

```
Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
int a = s.nextInt();
s.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
String b = s.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter another string: ");
String c=s.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter one more string: ");
String d=s.nextLine();

System.out.println(a+"\n"+b+d+c);
```

Ref:
[Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)